# scrapy CrawlSpider: modify deny rules list while crawling

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I need to update deny list in crawl rule while crawling website. (i.e. i want to dynamically modify deny rules list while my spider is working)

what i tried is

```
deny = ['a','b','c']
rules = ( Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/r/','/p/' ), deny=deny), callback='parse_item', follow=True), )
```

and then performed `self.deny.append(unique_category)` in `parse_item()` function but it did not worked as I expected: updated deny list was ignored(crawler still went to same category again and again).

I would appreciate any suggestions. thanks

Comment: do you get error message ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: excuse me for lack of explanation, furas. I've meant that crawler simply ignored appended rules.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Poke around in the internal APIs of the link extractors, which isn't guaranteed to survive version changes:

   ```
   self.rules[0].deny_res.append(re.compile('d'))
   ```
2. Make your own version (or subclass) of [`CrawlSpider`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/5b31dfe3c970f7e16dc911bb8b028a0fff54a7f9/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L34-L107) that does exactly what you want.